# Problem receiving from URL

Tags: android, inputstream

Hello I am receiving a JSON file from an URL in an Android device. I have no idea why I am getting just the first character of the JSON, this is a "{"  instead of 
`{"status":"OK","num_results":5,"results":[{"id":1,"title":"Apartamentos Campus"`,
Then is.available() is returning 1 all the time. 
The funny thing is that if I use in another device it receives everything.

I am using the wifi to connect.

And the output that I am getting is:

03-11 13:12:17.377: VERBOSE/Mixare(15816): attemps: 1

03-11 13:12:17.382: VERBOSE/Mixare(15816): is.available(): 1

03-11 13:12:17.462: VERBOSE/Mixare(15816): attemps: 1

03-11 13:12:17.482: VERBOSE/Mixare(15816): is.available(): 1

03-11 13:12:19.417: VERBOSE/Mixare(15816): attemps: 2

03-11 13:12:19.417: VERBOSE/Mixare(15816): is.available(): 1
...

And this is the code:

```
    public InputStream getHttpGETInputStream(String urlStr, int attemps) throws Exception {     
    URL u = new URL(urlStr);
    InputStream is = null;
    try{            
        URLConnection uc = u.openConnection();          
        is =  uc.getInputStream();          
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.v(MixView.TAG, "Excepcion leyendo inputStream: "+e.getMessage());           
    }
    Log.v(MixView.TAG, "attemps: "+attemps);
    Log.v(MixView.TAG, "is.available(): "+is.available());
    if(is.available() < 50 && attemps < 6){
        try {               
            Thread.sleep(2000);//para y lo vuelve a intentar descargar              
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
        attemps++;      
        is.close();
        return getHttpGETInputStream(urlStr,attemps);
    }       
    return is;
}
```

Comment: `available()` only returns the amount of bytes that are currently buffered, not the total length of the stream. Can you include the actual code where you're reading from the stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, You are reading the content in wrong way. Please use following code:

```
public static final byte[] getBytes(URLConnection conn ) throws IOException {
                final InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();      
                final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();         
                final byte[] b = new byte[256];
                int rv = 0;
                while ( ( rv = inputStream.read(b) ) != -1 ) baos.write(b, 0, rv);
                try  { inputStream.close(); } catch ( Exception e ) {};
            try  {
                final HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection)conn;                     
                        httpConn.disconnect();
            }
            catch ( Exception e ) {};       
            final byte[] bytes =  baos.toByteArray();
            baos.close();
            return bytes;
        }

        public static final String getResponse(URLConnection conn) throws IOException {
                final byte[] bytes = getBytes(conn);
            final String response = new String(bytes,"UTF-8");
            return response;
        }      

...
final JSONObject responseObj = new JSONObject(getResponse(your_url_connection));
...
```